# Moving to the next page using BeautifulSoup for scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I would need to scrape the content (just titles) from a website. I did it for one page, but I would need to do it for all the pages on the website.
Currently, I am doing as follows:

```
import bs4, requests
import pandas as pd
import re

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}
    
    
r = requests.get(website, headers=headers)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')


title=soup.find_all('h2')
```

I know that, when I move to the next page, the url changes as follows:

```
website/page/2/
website/page/3/
... 
website/page/49/
...
```

I tried to build a recursive function using next_page_url = base_url + next_page_partial but it does not move to the next page.

```
if soup.find("span", text=re.compile("Next")):
    page = "https://catania.liveuniversity.it/notizie-catania-cronaca/cronacacatenesesicilina/page/".format(page_num)
    page_num +=10 # I should scrape all the pages so maybe this number should be changed as I do not know at the beginning how many pages there are for that section
    print(page_num)
else:
    break
```

I followed this question (and answer): [Moving to next page for scraping using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54904441/moving-to-next-page-for-scraping-using-beautifulsoup)

Please let me know if you need more info. Many thanks

Updated code:

```
import bs4, requests
import pandas as pd
import re

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

page_num=1
website="https://catania.liveuniversity.it/notizie-catania-cronaca/cronacacatenesesicilina"

while True:
  r = requests.get(website, headers=headers)
  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')


  title=soup.find_all('h2')

  if soup.find("span", text=re.compile("Next")):
      page = f"https://catania.liveuniversity.it/notizie-catania-cronaca/cronacacatenesesicilina/page/{page_num}".format(page_num)
      page_num +=10
  else:
      break
```

Comment: The .format line needs a {} within the string where you want page_num to go I believe. Does that help with anything?

Comment: Before ```page_num```, "page/" seems to be added.

Comment: When you use .format, you don't need to add {} in .format().

Comment: No friend, as in `"website/page/{}".format(page_num)` I think though personally I use f strings so it would be `f"website/page/{page_num}"`

Comment: Oh apologies, too used to f strings

Comment: Oh, as @RolvApneseth told above, {} should be in the string before ```.format()```!

Comment: Are you trying to use .format like this: `txt3 = "My name is {}, I'am {}".format("John",36)` (Examples I found from https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp)

Comment: You have to initialize ```page_num``` before use because you used ```page_num+=10```. Try ```print(page)``` to check whether the page url is properly made or not.

Comment: can you please check the question? I updated it with all you suggestions, also including the page_num initialisation. I am still doing something wrong. It does not print any page. So I think there is some problem in the while cycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `f"url/{page_num}"` then remove `format(page_num)`.

You can use anything you want below:

`page = f"https://catania.liveuniversity.it/notizie-catania-cronaca/cronacacatenesesicilina/page/{page_num}"`

or

`page = "https://catania.liveuniversity.it/notizie-catania-cronaca/cronacacatenesesicilina/page/{}".format(page_num)`

Good luck!

---

Final answer will be this:

```
import bs4, requests
import pandas as pd
import re

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'}

page_num=1
website="https://catania.liveuniversity.it/notizie-catania-cronaca/cronacacatenesesicilina"

while True:
  r = requests.get(website, headers=headers)
  soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html')


  title=soup.find_all('h2')

  if soup.find("span", text=re.compile("Next")):
      website = f"https://catania.liveuniversity.it/notizie-catania-cronaca/cronacacatenesesicilina/page/{page_num}"
      page_num +=1
  else:
      break
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't check that. You updated the url into ```page```, but you use ```website``` in your request. please check that.

Comment: The changed url for scrapping is stored in ```page```, but when ```while``` starts again, ```r=requests()``` still get data from ```website```.

Comment: please try changing  ```page``` into ```website``` in ```if``` condition. and you still have  ```.format(page_num)``` which should be removed when you use ```f""```.

Comment: ```page_num += 1``` will be answer. At your first iteration, initialized ```website``` will be used. After that, ```page_num``` will be 2 at your second iteration because 1 was added to your initial value 1.

Comment: I updated my answer. Please take a look and let me know there is a problem.

Comment: I found that the if statement is wrong because the pages you want to scrap do not have any ```<span>Next</span>```. Please review the html codes of the pages. When the page has a next page, it have ```<a class="next page-numbers" href="https://catania.liveuniversity.it/notizie-catania-cronaca/cronacacatenesesicilina/page/{page_number}/">Successivo</a>```.